# Flot graph - lineWidth in realtime chart plotting

Tags: jquery, graph, line, real-time, flot

I am plotting realtime graph with jquery flot, and I am running 10-15 lines in the graph [count of line is dynamic, so could be some time 20 or more], Default lineWidth is 1, and for selected one I want to change lineWidth to 3.

I changed code to set data[index].lineWidth = 3 for selected line, but its not working.

Can anyone help about it, how to change lineWidth on the fly in running realtime flot graph ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The property "lineWidth" is a member of the lines collection.  Also, after you adjust your series appearance you have to make a call to plot.draw() to redraw with the new options.

For [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jNVM2/2/):

```
$(function () {
    var d1 = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < 14; i += 0.5)
         d1.push([i, Math.sin(i)]);

     var d2 = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]];

     // a null signifies separate line segments
     var d3 = [[0, 12], [7, 12], null, [7, 2.5], [12, 2.5]];

     var somePlot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ d1, d2, d3 ]);

    somePlot.getData()[1].lines.lineWidth = 20;
    somePlot.draw();

});
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

This helped me.
  somePlot.getData()[1].lines.lineWidth = 20;


Thanks.

Comment: Hi, We have same query as discussed you. we have a bar graph in which we are showing few statistics. As we know, in graph we pass statistics data in form of array. If all data has value greater than 0, then there is no issue with displaying graph. Now we want that, if some data are 0 then we can set the line width for that data array as 0. As result not line width display for 0 value data. We have tried your solution but nothing work. Please share us the solution of this issue, if you have.

Comment: @user2393886 : I had a problem getting this to work as well. The reason in my case was that I called `plot.setData(data)` after changing the options (and before calling `plot.draw()`) which apparently resets the options. Could that be the solution to your issue?